# how to Convert String to byte array and byte array to Blob using only java program

Tags: java

Question is:

```
String strContent = "Hello Hi How are you ";
byte[] byteConent = strContent.getBytes();
```

But further I want convert to Blob only in Java program

Because I m working on some script for MySQL DB by default for our application.

Regards,
Satish

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 Blob blob = connection.createBlob();
 blob.setBytes(1, bytes);
```

Where connection is the connection to db object.

Comment: hi, i making script only in simple core java program. Becoz that script when run automatically all the Mysql DB will create. becoz when we working on any java project initially script very much requirement...so that why asking

Comment: @user1032427 sorry i dont get qhat you are.trying to say

Answer (score 2):

```
Blob blob=null; 
blob=new SerialBlob(byteContent);
```

Comment: hi, i making script only in simple core java program. Becoz that script when run automatically all the Mysql DB will create.